# Keycloak: Check if a user attribute exists while registering a user. How to make user attribute unique per-users?

Tags: keycloak, idp

I have added a user attribute and its mapper in the client. Now, when a user registers, the user will enter that attribute as a part of the registration. But I need to make sure that the same user attribute value is not entered by multiple users. So I need to check for its existence before registering a user. How can I do that?

Comment: You can implement on of the **SPIs** that Keycloak provides. And, listen for `CREATE` event and perform necessary checks. I had a similar requirement and did it this way.

Comment: @adarsh Can you provide more detail, or point me to resources needed for it. How do we listen for `CREATE` event? Or are there any Providers related to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the **SPI** that Keycloak provides for your custom requirements.
Keycloak [SPI documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_providers) is a good starting point. You could implement an `EventListener` as in [this](https://dev.to/adwaitthattey/building-an-event-listener-spi-plugin-for-keycloak-2044) example.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement a similar thing in my project. I’ve created a custom validator that validates attribute uniqueness. Here is the validator class:

```java
package com.dawidgora.provider;

import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.RealmModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserProvider;
import org.keycloak.provider.ConfiguredProvider;
import org.keycloak.provider.ProviderConfigProperty;
import org.keycloak.validate.AbstractStringValidator;
import org.keycloak.validate.ValidationContext;
import org.keycloak.validate.ValidationError;
import org.keycloak.validate.ValidatorConfig;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class UniqueAttributeValidatorProvider extends AbstractStringValidator implements ConfiguredProvider {
    public static final String ID = "unique-attribute";
    public static final String MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_UNIQUE = "error.duplicated.attribute";
    private static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configProperties = new ArrayList<>();

    public UniqueAttributeValidatorProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doValidate(String attributeValue, String attributeName, ValidationContext context, ValidatorConfig config) {
        KeycloakSession session = context.getSession();

        UserModel currentUser = (UserModel) context.getAttributes().get(UserModel.class.getName());

        if (!isAttributeUnique(attributeValue, attributeName, session, currentUser)) {
            context.addError(new ValidationError(ID, attributeName, MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_UNIQUE + '.' + attributeName));
        }
    }

    public boolean isAttributeUnique(String attributeValue, String attributeName, KeycloakSession session, UserModel currentUser) {
        UserProvider userProvider = session.getProvider(UserProvider.class);

        RealmModel realm = this.getRealm(session);

        Stream<UserModel> usersWithSameAttributeValue = userProvider.searchForUserByUserAttributeStream(realm, attributeName, attributeValue);

        return currentUser != null
            ? usersWithSameAttributeValue.filter(user -> !user.getId().equals(currentUser.getId())).findAny().isEmpty()
            : usersWithSameAttributeValue.findAny().isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "Unique Attribute";
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return configProperties;
    }

    RealmModel getRealm(KeycloakSession session) {
        if (session.getContext() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (session.getContext().getRealm() != null) {
            return session.getContext().getRealm();
        }
        if (session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession() != null
                && session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().getRealm() != null) {
            return session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().getRealm();
        }
        if (session.getContext().getClient() != null
                && session.getContext().getClient().getRealm() != null) {
            return session.getContext().getClient().getRealm();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope that will help someone because I couldn’t find much help online on this topic.

Comment: Additionally, I've isolated the code to separate github repository: https://github.com/dawidgora/keycloak-unique-attribute-validator-provider 

You should be able to test it by running `docker compose up -d`.